# Are object properties ordered now?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I noticed that the ECMAScript definitions for Objects have changed from the 3rd edition to the 5th and 6th.

3rd edition

```
4.3.3 Object
An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of
properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A
function stored in a property of an object is called a method.
```

5th and 6th edition

```
4.3.3
object
member of the type Object.
NOTE An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype
object. The prototype may be the null value.
```

Since it no longer says an **unordered** collection of properties, does that mean they are ordered now? and for JavaScript too?

Comment: No, that does not mean they are ordered, there's still no order in objects

Comment: It's in the specs, [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4), *"The mechanics and order of enumerating properties is not specified."*.

Comment: @adeneo Note that that ES5 rule has been superseded by the ES6 rule of `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`, which provides specific rules for property enumeration order. (Whether that's been *implemented* is another story, of course.)

Comment: @apsillers - indeed, it seems ES2015 has some implied order based on insertion, but we're still a long way from being able to rely on it.

Comment: @apsillers: No it's still in the ES6 spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate .

Comment: @FelixKling Neat! I see now from the duplicate that I also misunderstood `[[Enumerate]]`'s dependency on `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` (i.e., it does not preserve order).

Comment: @adeneo I was wrong! `:O`

Answer (score 3):

Sort-of, at least in the sixth edition (emphasis mine):

> #### 9.1.12 [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )
>
> When the [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of O is called the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let keys be a new empty List.
> 2. For each own property key P of O that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
>
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 3. For each own property key P of O that is a String but is not an integer index, **in property creation order**
>
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 4. For each own property key P of O that is a Symbol, **in property creation order**
>
>    a. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 5. Return keys.

The specification relies on the insertion order of properties, implying that the order must be part of the object. It also specifies that `for in` loops must use this order (see 7.3.21 and 19.1.2.14). However, [browsers do not entirely respect this in all cases](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?.id=164), so you shouldn't rely on it.

[The ES6 Map type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) also specifies insertion order for iteration. I believe that this case *is* respected by all browsers, so you should prefer it if you need to rely on this behaviour.

Comment: Notice that this only defines an order for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, not for `for … in` loops or `Object.keys` as one might have expected.

Comment: And of course, you should *never* rely on it. If you need a collection with defined order, use a `Map`.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm... I'm not sure I'm parsing this right, but I think that for-in uses [[Enumerate]] which uses [[GetOwnPropertyKeys]], which enforces this order for properties that are coming from the same object. The spec says "the order is not specified", but its requirements do seem to require this order... I guess it could meant that it needs to obtain the keys using [[GetOwnPropertyKeys]]'s approach, but the implementation is free to return them in a different order. In any case, yes, use a `Map`. (edit: I see you've discussed this specifically in the duplicate target.)

Comment: *"I guess it could meant that it needs to obtain the keys using [[GetOwnPropertyKeys]]'s approach, but the implementation is free to return them in a different order."* Yes. That was clarified in https://esdiscuss.org/topic/property-ordering-of-enumerate-getownpropertynames .

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Would it then be possible to shuffle the order of a Map?

Comment: @MarcoChan You'd need to remove and re-insert every element, in the new order.